# Casting SqlDataType to C# Enum

Tags: c#, sql, design-patterns, enums

This is part of a process to do 1-1 Table.Column-Class.Property matching automatically. I'm trying to cover the bases for each possible base type as [listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx). I've been working with ORM's more and more but now I've gone back to an environment where they're doing `Id = row["Id"] as int` but instead of doing that brute force way of casting I just used attributes on the Properties so that I could write `DataTable.ExtractAs<MyClass>` which attempts to create and `IList<MyClass>` based on those attributes.

My questions is: Is there a better way to handle casting from a SqlDataType to a C# enum that covers all integral types?

Right now I'm doing this:

```
internal static bool TrySetValue<T>(T t, PropertyInfo property, DataRow row, string columnName)
{
    Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;

    // other logic and unique cases

    if (propertyType.IsEnum 
        && Enum.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType) == value.GetType())
    {
        property.SetValue(t, value, null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is this overkill? Is there a better way to do this? I don't see any member within `PropertyInfo` that addresses these integral types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enum.ToObject(object)` which will handle conversion from `SByte`, `Byte`, `Int16`, `UInt16`, `Int32`, `UInt32`, `Int64` and `UInt64` to an enum:

```
if (propertyType.IsEnum) {
    property.SetValue(Enum.ToObject(value));
}
```